# What do these numbers mean in the output of iptable-save?

Tags: iptables

In the output of `iptables-save`

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.3.8 on Sun Mar 14 19:42:45 2010
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [328764:37367248]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [324693:28884726]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Mar 14 19:42:45 2010
```

What do the numbers 328764:37367248 mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained [**here**](http://www.faqs.org/docs/iptables/iptables-save.html):

> This contains a few comments starting with a # sign. Each table is marked like `*<table-name>`, for example *mangle. Then within each table we have the chain specifications and rules. A chain specification looks like : `<chain-name> <chain-policy> [<packet-counter>:<byte-counter>]`.

So 328764 is the number of packets and 37367248 is the number of bytes.

Comment: Thanks. That mean I can set them all to zero when I use iptables-restore, right?